# How to unjoin desktops between monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

The title is a little bit unclear, but it's difficult to explain it in one row.

Windows 10 has the possibility to create multiple desktops but when you switch between them, the other monitor switches it too. How can I switch desktop only in one monitor and the other being always the same?

Comment: This cannot be done on Windows.  You can only activate one virtual Desktop at a time.